# Tab bar shows unwanted white top space

Tags: ios, swift

Hi there I'm using `storyboard` only to design the main scene.
The problem I'm trying to deal with is little white space on top of my `Tabbar`. Here is screenshot how it looks like

[image]

Any help how can I remove that?

Notice that I have set the bottom constraint to zero by auto layout as shown in following picture

[bottom constraint for last object in the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0mnF.png)

Comment: Please consider revealing how you set the bottom constraint to zero ?

Comment: @RatulSharker please have a look again, picture added

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take another look at your constraints. Consider using "Add missing constraints"

Comment: Thank you Alex for your suggestion but the " Add missing constraints" is not allowed when I select the view ( It's gray and not allowed to click )

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking `constrain to margins` before you click add constraints.